# Copy ubuntu to USB without free space

Tags: windows, backup, vmware, usb-drive, dd

I want to take a copy of my Ubuntu OS to a usb as an image where I can use this image later with a VM in Windows PC.

My usb stick is 16 GB (14.7GB actually) and the Ubuntu hard disk is 250 while the used space is only 10 GB. I can't use `dd` as it will also copy the whole 250GB and ***I only want to copy the used 10GB***.

Also, don't tell me to use `gzip` as if I even compress it, I need to extract it again and my other PC with the VM is only 250GB hard disk.

Comment: There are methods for this task. Some are easier, some are more complicated. The best alternative depends on how your Ubuntu is installed. 1) Is it installed in UEFI mode (or BIOS alias CSM alias legacy mode)? Is there an MSDOS partition table or a GUID partition table (GPT)? Which version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: It's not totally clear (to me) the size of your Ubuntu OS.  It appears you're saying the Ubuntu OS drive is 250 GB and it's currently only using 10 Gigs of the available space.  The steps will depend on the physical size of the OS drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Gparted to resize the Ubuntu OS installation to a size small
   enough to fit on your USB drive.  You can resize it to 12GB.
2. Use DD or a GUI drive backup utility such as Clonezilla to backup
   the 12GB drive to the USB stick.  Your USB stick should now be
   bootable as if it were your original hard drive.
3. For Virtualization converting the USB drive to VDI use
   VBoxManager.
4. You can store the 12 GIG USB drive as an image DD or Ubuntu's GUI
   Disk Manager.

### The Steps in detail

- **Resiz3 the Disk.**

You'll have to use a Live session (or a different boot drive to run Gparted.  The drive can't be in used while performing the resize.

- **Backup your Disk to the USB stick.**

You can back it up with this commandline using DD:

```
$ dd if=[source drive/image] of=[destination drive or image] bs=4M status=progress
```

```
Source Drive - The USB stick (ie /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, etc)
Destination drive or image:
```

You can also use the GUI method via [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to backup the harddrive to USB drive (or an image).

- **Convert to a Virtual Disk**

If you backed up the drive as an image, use this command to create a VirtualBox image:

```
$ VBoxManage convertdd input.img output.vdi
```

Use this command to create the VirtualBox image from the USB drive itself:

```
$ VBoxManage convertfromraw /dev/sdX MyImage.vdi --format VDI
```

*(The `/dev/sdX` will be `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, (or the appropriate device of your USB drive.))*

**You can transfer Device to Device using Clonezilla**

The Clonezilla application has the option of transferring your USB drive (device) directly to your HardDrive (device).

**Summary**

After you have transferred the Smaller USB drive to the larger Hard Drive, you will have to use Gparted to resize the Drive/Partitions to regain the space available on the larger hard drive.

Comment: The `dd` method works with MSDOS partition tables, but need fixing if there is a GUID partition table (GPT). You can use `gdisk` to fix it (the backup partition table at the tail end of the drive). Maybe new versions of Clonezilla can do it all the way also for GPT, but at least earlier versions were not happy to clone to a smaller drive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and information.I tested the steps before posting them.  You're right, that there is a method for using Clonezilla to backup to a smaller drive or partition.  I have experimented with that in the past (when it wasn't built-in, but a tricky method for doing it.  I didn't include those details because the the OP's main objective was described as a backup excluding the free space (which using Gparted to shrink the big drive will achieve that.  The restore from the USB drive (or image) will certainly be to a drive that's larger than the 12GB backup.